# Implementing widget system in codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, widget, inline-code

I was developing an application using codeigniter PHP , where in i am into a problem and hoping to get proper guidance over here. Problem goes like this.

I want to implement widget system in codeigniter. That means in my view file i want to create widgets that calls different controllers , which inturn loads another view. which means i want to do something like "inline code"...if i call a controller that particula controller loading view must get replaced in calling function line.
The call to that widget can be made from anywhere from any view.

Is it possible in codeigniter or any way i can do it ? i have been looking through web but couldnt find proper answer.

Comment: I would recommend using HMVC for widgets

Comment: What is other option other than HMVC ? Can we do similar in MVC itself ?

Comment: Non that I know of HMVC very easy because you can create modules etc HMVC plug in for codeigniter https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc